# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open fs.createWriteStream

Tags: node.js, azure, zip, filestream, fs

I am using node js function **fs.createWriteStream** in azure instance to download ZIP file from third party but it's giving me error "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\data\499037.zip'"

Below is my code sample.

```
    let filePath = '%HOME%\data\'+pathName+'.zip'; 
    let file = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);
        file.on('open', async function(fd) { 
        //Here is code to process file 
        }).on('error', function(err) {
        context.log('File store error ==> '+err); 
        file.end(); 
        });
```

Please suggest what is the exact issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try add backslash before `%HOME%` -> `\%HOME%`.
It may help you split `wwwroot` folder to `www\root`.
Also pay attention that in your js backslash seems to wrongly escape quote

```js
let filePath = '%HOME%\data\'+pathName+'.zip'; 
//                          ^
// should be
let filePath = '\%HOME%\data\\'+pathName+'.zip';
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
I have tried above solution as well but it's showing me below error message.
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\%HOME%data\795498.zip'

Comment: where does your file stored? could you provide correct path to it?

Comment: I have updated code in azure instance with updated path 'D:\\local\\Temp\\'+pathName+'.zip'; and it's working fine.

Comment: feel free to mark answer is useful to mark question as resolved